# How do I get IIS to render Mercurial (Python Module) static content? (ie, images, styles)

Tags: iis, mercurial, iis-7.5

I'm trying to setup an IIS server to expose my Mercurial repositories. I've followed a [number](http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/02/24/running-a-mercurial-server-on-iis-7-5-windows-server-2008-r2) of [tutorials](http://win1337ist.wordpress.com/tag/mercurial-iis-7/), but seem to be getting the same issue.

Basically, I'm able to get Python installed and mapped correctly in IIS, as well as (from what I can tell) the  Mercurial module. However, none of the static content that I expect to see in the Mercurial web application is properly rendered. (For example, the Mercurial logo from the static directory isn't rendered). I know that the Python/CGI processing is configured correctly because my actual repositories are exposed properly.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the content from `templates` directory of the `mercurial` Python module into your mapped web application directory.

For example, at the default installation paths, you'll want to copy the contents of

```sh
C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\mercurial\templates
```

into where you've defined your Mercurial application in IIS, i.e.,

```sh
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hg
```